# VS2015 Macro to parse function names from a list and create any missing functions in the class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, macros

I have a state machine I have created for work applications that is defined by a recursive structure that can have any number of substeps per step. The format is like this:

```
        StateMachine.InitializeStates((
        base.WorkerStateMachine = new StepDefinition(IsRootStep: true, RootState: base.WorkerState)
        {
            Name = base.ThreadNameRef,
            SubSteps = new List<StepDefinition>()
                {
            new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step1", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step1Function) },
            new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step2",
                SubSteps = new List<StepDefinition>()
                {
                    new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step2,1", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step2,1Function) },
                    new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step2,2", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step2,2Function) },
                    new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step2,3", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step2,3Function) },
                    new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step2,4", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step2,4Function) },
                }
            },
            new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step3", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step3Function) },
            new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step4",
                SubSteps = new List<StepDefinition>()
                {
                    new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step4,1", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step4,1Function) },
                    new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step4,2",
                        SubSteps = new List<StepDefinition>()
                        {
                            new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step4,2,1", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step4,2,1Function) },
                            new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step4,2,2", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step4,2,2Function) },
                            new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step4,2,3", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step4,2,3Function) },
                            new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step4,2,4", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step4,2,4Function) },
                        }
                    },
                    new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step4,3", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step4,3Function) },
                    new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step4,4", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step4,4Function) },
                }
            },
            new StepDefinition() { Name = "Step5", Delagate = new CallFunction(Step5Function) },
                }

        }
        ));
```

The functions all need to be formed inside the "StateMachine Functions (Add new steps here)" region like this:

```
#region StateMachine Functions (Add new steps here)

private bool Step1Function(StepDefinition CurrentStep)
{
    return false;
}

#endregion
```

What I would like to do is have a macro for Visual Studio (I am currently using 2015) that will parse over my state machine structure, get a list of all the function names, order any functions that are currently in the region to match the state machine order, then add prototypes for any functions that are missing in the class.

From a parsing stand point this would be pretty easy to do in C#, but I have never done a VS macro and have no idea where to even begin.

I envision having a macro that can either find the structure on its own in the current class, or could start with just the highlighted text. I don't really know what is possible with the VS macros.

If anyone can help get me started I would greatly appreciate it!

John Vickers

Comment: There is no built-in support for macros in Visual Studio 2015. However, even if you had access to VBA macros I would think that this technology is unsuitable for solving your problem. I guess you can use Roslyn to parse and generate code but is it worth the effort? Another option is to code generate the state machine using whatever method you prefer based on a definition in a simpler form.

Comment: To create a VS 2015 macro command in C# you can use my Visual Commander extension https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/